# failed to set value to the formControl

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to set value to a formConfrol  Field **ReferCode**, by taking value of a variable coming from Route name **reff** , 
where I am unable to set it

I am sharing code

**ts >**

```
ReferCode = new FormControl('');
  Refrr : any;
  constructor(

    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
     this.user = new FormGroup({
    'ReferCode': this.ReferCode,
    });
    this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     this.Refrr = params['referral'];
     console.log(this.Refrr);
     if(this.Refrr){
     this.user.controls['ReferCode'].setValue(this.Refrr);
     this.user.controls['ReferCode'].patchValue(this.Refrr);
     }
```

**html**

```
 <form class="signin-form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="user_signup(user)" [formGroup]="user">

            <mat-form-field class="form-input-width">
              <input
                matInput
                placeholder="Enter Referral Code: (Optional)"
                value=""
                name="ReferCode"
                [(ngModel)]="referCode"
                formControlName="ReferCode"
              />

      <button mat-button >
        Sign Up
      </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: can you remove `[(ngModel)]="referCode"` and try again.

Comment: yes I think you can't use ngModule and formControl together

Comment: @MohammadrezaImani Exactly!!!

Comment: `ReferCode` is a standalone form control but you seem to update a form group called `user`. Are the two bound in any way ?

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the `value` and `[(ngModel)]` attribute
- Use only one from [`setValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue) and [`patchValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#patchvalue)

> *This function is functionally the same as setValue at this level. It exists for symmetry with patchValue on FormGroups and FormArrays, where it does behave differently.*

So your HTML Code will be

```
<form class="signin-form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="user_signup(user)" [formGroup]="user ">
    <mat-form-field class="form-input-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter Referral Code: (Optional)" name="ReferCode" formControlName="ReferCode" />
  </mat-form-field>
<button mat-button>Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tesj8a-iy3akt)

Answer (score 0):

In template driven forms to set values to part of the form

```
@ViewChild('f') signupForm: NgForm;
this.signupForm.form.patchValue({
userData: {
    username: suggestedName
  }
});
```

In reactive forms, you can use

```
signupForm: FormGroup;
this.signupForm.patchValue({
userData: {
    username: 'suggestedName'
  }
});
```

you can set default values inside `ngOnInit()` or using a click event (within a method).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is like this use `patchValue()`.

Try this out, it will definitely help you a lot in future too

```
this.user.patchValue({ReferCode:this.Refrr})
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<form class="signin-form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="user_signup(user)" [formGroup]="user">
    <mat-form-field class="form-input-width">
        <input
                matInput
                placeholder="Enter Referral Code: (Optional)" 
                name="ReferCode" 
                formControlName="ReferCode"
        />
    </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-button >
            Sign Up
        </button>
</form>
```

TS:

```
this.user.setValue('ReferCode', this.Refrr);
```